# Image hot spot navigate url on click changes parent page url c#

Tags: c#, jquery

I am using imagemap in c# where I am giving navigate url to image map in code behind.I want new page to come up as popup which I have succeeded.but In mozilla My parent page changes url to :

```
"javascript:window.open('WebForm1.aspx','Graph','height=600,width=900');"
```

It works fine in chrome

My c# code for binding url to hotspots is like this:

```
RectangleHotSpot rh;


rh = new RectangleHotSpot();

rh.Top =  0;
rh.Bottom =500 ;
rh.Left = 0 ;
rh.Right = 500 ;
rh.NavigateUrl = "javascript:window.open('default.aspx','Graph','height=600,width=900');";

ImgMp.HotSpots.Add(rh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Target`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hotspot.target.aspx) property and set it to: `_blank`.

Change your code to:

```
rh.NavigateUrl = "default.aspx";
rh.Target = "_blank";
```

Comment: Brother it only opens a new window in text tab, as in question i have mentioned I have succeeded in displaying popup with this method but the problem is with the mozilla browser. When popup comes up parent window url changes to :   javascript:window.open('WebForm1.aspx','Graph','height=600,width=900');

Comment: Also that window is blank